# Cardinality of $Q_n=\{x_1x_2\dots x_n \mid x_i\in\{a,b,c\}, x_i\neq x_{i+1}, x_1\neq x_n\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider words consisting of $n$ letters which have the following form:

$$W_n=\{x_1x_2\dots x_n \mid  x_i\neq x_{i+1}, x_i\in\{a,b,c\}\}$$
$$Q_n=\{x\in W_n \mid  x_1\neq x_n\}$$

I want to determine $|W_n|$ and $|Q_n|$.

For $W_n$ we have $|W_n|=3\times2\times2\times\dots\times2=3\times2^{n-1}$.

I think I need a recursion for $|Q_n|$ but I don't know.

$|Q_n|=3\times2^{n-1}-?$

Comment: If you define $R_n=\{x\in W_n \mid  x_1 = x_n\}$, then you can find a system of recurrence equations for $Q_{n+1}=a Q_n +b R_n$ and $R_{n+1}=c Q_n +d R_n$. Then the system has solution $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}0\\3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Also, if you’re familiar with eigenvectors, you can find those for that matrix, then decompose that initial vector into $c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$, and get a solution in the form $c_1 \lambda_1^{n-1} v_1 + c_2 \lambda_2^{n-1} v_2$. Once you do that, you can just take the equation for the $Q$ component.

Comment: Solve it for small values of $n$, guess the pattern, then try to prove it by induction. In a pinch, look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: That’s certainly a useful technique that works often on small problems, but in this case the matrix takes a minute to find, and being a rather simple 2x2 its eigenvectors take about 2 minutes to find. So it’s a rather quick problem to solve using the straightforward method.